# rails passenger + apache segmentation bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

Ive got a problem with running rails on apache + passenger. When I goto the site, I get in the /var/log/apache:

```
[Tue Nov 13 21:54:21 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

*** Exception EOFError in spawn manager (Unexpected end-of-file detected.) (process 22878):
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:306:in `unmarshal_and_raise_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:71:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:61
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

*** Exception EOFError in spawn manager (Unexpected end-of-file detected.) (process 22944):
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:306:in `unmarshal_and_raise_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:71:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:61
[ pid=22882 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-11-13 21:54:26.950 ]:
  Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/home/xxx/xxx/xxx': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

*** Exception EOFError in spawn manager (Unexpected end-of-file detected.) (process 22950):
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:306:in `unmarshal_and_raise_errors'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:71:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in `spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
    from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:61
[ pid=22881 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-11-13 21:54:28.23 ]:
  Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/home/xxx/xxx/xxx': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
  Backtrace:
     (empty)
```

I really don't know what it is. Application is running ok when I write rails server.

any clue for this issue? :(

best regards

Comment: Judging by line 2, it looks like a bug in the mysql2 gem.  Make sure you're using the latest version of that to start with (Note:  Passenger uses its own set of gems - not the same ones as your regular Rails installation!).

Comment: I've set SetEnv GEM_PATH /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320 and there /gems/ I have in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems => mysql2 (0.3.11) hmm

Comment: Well, that's the latest version...  But I just noticed something else:  On line 2 it mentions Ruby 1.9.2, but on line 3 it talks about Ruby 1.8.7...  Looks like a potential conflict there.

Comment: exactly! but how to solve this?

Comment: My guess?  Upgrade Passenger.  The latest version, 3.0.17, definitely supports Ruby 1.9.2 (1.9.3, actually), while 2.2.11 probably doesn't (I'm guessing this is where the 1.8.7 came from).

Comment: hmm its very strange root@serwer:/# passenger-config --version
3.0.18
but why it says  Phusion_Passenger/2.2.11 configured hmm?